# List - int comparatives

Tags: python, string, list, function, int

Here I am trying to get an input from the user which is added to a list, then the list must be validated before I run it through another function. I know that I need to change something for the comparative to work: can only be used with integers and the input in the list will be a string. Also there is an error that says "unorderable types: str() > int(). How do I get around this ?

```
def strInput():
string = []
string = str(input("Please enter numbers from 1-999... "))
if validate(string):
    return string
else:
    strInput()

def validate(i):
    if i > 0 and i <= 999:
        return True
    else:
        strInput()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to collect a list of numbers. The code below will do the trick

```
def validate(userInput):
    return userInput.isdigit() and int(userInput) > 0 and int(userInput) <= 999

def getListOfNumbers():
    listOfNumbers = []
    while True:
        userInput = raw_input("Please enter a number from 1 to 999. Enter 0 to finish input: ")
        if userInput == '0':
            return listOfNumbers
        elif validate(userInput):
            listOfNumbers.append(int(userInput))
        #optional
        else:
            continue
myList = getListOfNumbers()
print myList
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be: either do this:

```
if int(i) > 0 and int(i) <= 999:
```

if you in python 3 `input` takes input as string
or do this:

```
string = int(input("Please enter numbers from 1-999... "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert the string into a integer. Try:

```
def validate(i):
    if i.isdigit() and int(i) > 0 and int(i) <= 999:
        return True
    else:
        strInput()
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps

```
def validate(i):
    try:
        num = int(i)
    except:
        return False
    return num > 0 and num <= 999

def strInput():
    string = str(input("Please enter numbers from 1-999... "))
    if validate(string):
        return string
    else:
        return strInput()

strings = []
strings.append(strInput())
strings.append(strInput())
print (strings)
```

prints out

```
Please enter numbers from 1-999... 1
Please enter numbers from 1-999... a
Please enter numbers from 1-999... 2
['1', '2']
```